# Troubles with creating zombie processes

Tags: c, linux, process

I am a student currently studying programming and am working on creating and closing processes. I was able to create this program that takes arguments from Bash and `argv[1]` is the amount of children the process will create. `argv[2]` determines which of these children creates another child. Now I want to have `argv[3]` make that number of the child processes (from `argv[1]`) to become zombies. I also have to somehow put a "fail-safe" so that the child processes first `exit()` the grandchild before they become zombies.

I have succeeded in making the first two arguments work.

**The code is:**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, antal, grandchild; pid_t pid, pid2;
    antal=atoi(argv[1]);
    grandchild=atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("antal=%d.\n grandchild=%d\n\n", antal,grandchild);
    for(i=0; i<antal; i++)
    {
        pid=fork();
        switch(pid)
        {
            case -1:
                fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed!");
                break;

            case 0:
                printf("Child process: %d.\n", getpid());
                sleep(1);
                if(i+1==grandchild)
                    pid2=fork();
                    if(pid2==0)
                    {
                        printf("I am the grandchilde with PID: %d.\n",getpid());
                        sleep(5);
                        exit(0);
                    }
                wait(0);
                exit(0);
                break;

            default: printf("Parent process with PID: %d\n", getpid());
                wait(0);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

I am having trouble understanding how I can go about doing this. I am 6 months into my course so I do not have extensive programming skills. Any help or tips on the subject is very much appreciated. I also would be very grateful for any sites that have good information on this matter.

Also are switches considered to be the reading friendliest option for controlling `fork()` return values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All processes will become zombies after they `exit()`; they will be removed once their parent process `wait()`s for them. If the parent process dies, they will be inherited by the init process, which basically does nothing much except call `wait()` in a loop once it's finished initializing the system. So, as soon as your process exits, *all* your zombies will be put to their grave by init very quickly. And as soon as your child exits (or calls `wait()`, as in your program), your grandchild won't be a zombie any more either.

So to see the zombies in `ps -a`, you'd have to put something like a `sleep(1000)` at the end of your program to prevent it from exiting.

Your child, that has the grandchild, shouldn't `wait()` either. Try something like

```
while (kill(pid, 0)!=-1)
    sleep(1);
```

to wait until the process has exited (killing with signal number 0 does nothing at all, but it fails if the process doesn't exist. It might fail for other reasons as well, but those normally won't apply here).

Not that what you're trying to do here is ok for educational purposes, but if you ever try this in "real" programs, the unix daemons will descend upon you in your sleep and haunt you in ways you don't even want to think about.

Comment: I have never before used the kill() command. So if I understood correctly, by adding     kill(pid, 0)!=-1  in the code of the child spawning the grandchild it would wait for the grandchild to successfully exit?

Comment: "successfully exit"? I've never heard of an unsuccessful exit ;-) But to answer your question: kill(pid,0) just detects the presence of a process with that pid. It returns 0 if that process exists (and is not a zombie), and -1 if the process has terminated. So the `kill` is used to detect if the process is still running, and the `while .. sleep` waits until the process is not running anymore.

Comment: I tried adding that piece of code instead of wait() in the child containing the grandchild and it just made the program freeze (i think  it just became a zombie).

Answer (score 0):

Besides what Guntram Blohm wrote, you obviously have forgotten braces here:

```
            if(i+1==grandchild)
                pid2=fork();
                if(pid2==0)
                {
                    printf("I am the grandchilde with PID: %d.\n",getpid());
                    sleep(5);
                    exit(0);
                }
```

(A good compiler with appropriate options would have warned that pid2 might be uninitialized.)

You might write

```
            if (i+1==grandchild)
                if (fork()==0)
                {
                    printf("I am the grandchilde with PID: %d.\n",getpid());
                    sleep(5);
                    exit(0);
                }
```

instead.